# JavaScript development addon for browsers

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, opera, devtools

Is there an addon that assists JavaScript (client-side) web development in browsers other than Firefox, for which [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com) suffices?

Especially something for Internet Explorer (version 7) and Opera (version  9) with which I'm currently experiencing issues.

Information about development tools like Firebug, are welcome for any browser.

Comment: Opera 9 is a bit old, the current version (Opera 11) has much better developer tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html)?

Comment: Hope it is compatible on most browsers though! Yeah, should be, considering it is a dev tool.

Comment: @Jeremy Rudd: According to the Firebug Lite webpage, it works in IE, Opera, and Safari.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using IE8 - Press F12 and you will see the fantastic developer tool window.

If you are using earlier versions [IE Developer Toolba](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en)r maybe handy.

For Opera you can use [DragonFly](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/introduction-to-opera-dragonfly/#gettingdragonfly) or [this](http://operawiki.info/WebDevToolbar) might help

Answer (score 2):

[Safari 4 (beta) (for both Mac and PC](http://www.apple.com/safari/)) may help you, but after you download it and install it you'll need to go into your preferences and turn on the Developer settings, then restart Safari.  This will give you a `Developer` file menu item with choices to change the User Agent, JavaScript Profiler and Debugger and a great little Web Inspector window (either docked or floating) which gives you access to (X)HTML, CSS, Resources (assets and timing), JavaScript, JavaScript Profiling and HTML5 database.

In addition it gives you a JavaScript console so you can make calls into the current rendered page to check for settings, variables, DOM walking and many other various little goodies, all in real-time.  Quite powerful and really nice.

Once you've tweeked what you're tweeking, simply copy your changes (or note them then) make the changes to your source.  I've only started accessing the power of it and I have to say, it's so far been a real joy to use - surprisingly so.

Answer (score 1):

For IE just get IE8, the built-in dev tools are pretty good.  If you need to test IE7 behaviour use compatiblity mode.  Of course you may wish to do a final test on IE7 itself (and you can download Script debugger and dev tools to work with IE7 but thats not as slick).

Comment: Yeah, and the rendering engine is pretty good too, defeating the purpose of debugging issues with IE6 and IE7.

Comment: In compatability mode IE8 has the same rendering bugs as IE7.  However the tools for analysing the DOM/CSS and debuging javascript are better.  The question is about debugging not testing the two are separate issues.  I'm fairly sure if you have a problem in IE7 you can reproduce on IE8 with compatability on however the tools for finding the problem are better on IE8.

Comment: Also note the question relates to Javascript debugging, the developer tool bar doesn't help there.

Answer (score 1):

[IE Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en)

Opera? Never an option! Webkit may be more important.

Comment: Great that it works with both IE7 and IE6. This is simply great.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en) for IE.

Answer (score 1):

Safari 4's [Web Inspector](http://www.apple.com/safari/features.html#developer) is great.

Steve

Comment: Safari for windows? I don't have a Mac.

Comment: Apple do make a version of Safari for Windows, if that's what you mean. I've only used the Web Inspector in Safari 4 for Mac, but it should be the same in the Windows version.

Comment: Safari is using Webkit, so you can simply go debug with Google Chrome (also using Webkit) and forget about Safari.