# What are best firebug equivalents for other browsers?

Tags: javascript

I sometimes need to debug JS in other browsers, and it would be really nice if they all had Firebug - failing that, what's the closest they have?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887216/which-tools-do-you-use-to-debug-html-js-in-your-browser
and also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/810619/javascript-development-addon-for-browsers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite)

Comment: Firebug Lite doesn't let you debug JS, it's nice for examining HTML and CSS, but JS debugging is not supported in Lite version.

Answer (score 3):

IE8 - Developer Tools (F12)
IE6,7,8 - Visual Studio/Microsoft Script Debugger/DynaTrace (for tracing JS, not debugging)
Chrome, Safari - Developer Tools.

Answer (score 2):

- Firebug Lite - any up-to-date browser, but limited
- IE - number of options depending of IE version and do you have Visual Studio
- Opera - Dragonfly
- Webkit based browsers have inspector and debugger in menu

IMHO Firebug is the best tool but could be used only on Firefox

Answer (score 2):

Opera has the excellent dragonfly developer console, which can profile your code (to find bottlenecks and redundent code) as well as step through breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

For Safari and Google Chrome, the **Developer Tools**.

Just right-click anywhere and select "Inspect Element", or use the **Ctrl + Shift + J** shortcut:

[Developer Tools http://img79.imageshack.us/img79/426/devtools.png](http://img79.imageshack.us/img79/426/devtools.png)

Comment: Developer Tools is actually a part of WebKit. :)

Comment: I like the stackoverflow background :)

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler is the one I use: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

There is Charles: http://www.charlesproxy.com/
Also WireShark: http://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: Those are very nice tools, but not really in the same class as Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

How about [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite)? It claims to work in IE, Opera and Safari by simply being a Javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug can be used in other browser with it's javascript version : hhttp://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Anyway, in Safari there is Web Inspector which is brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

IE has the [developer toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en).

Comment: IE8 has this built in; in fact, it's a better one (at least IMO). The Developer Toolbar won't load in IE8 anyway, you'll need to use the built-in one instead of the linked one.